# To get proper file path

Tags: android, android-intent

I've selected the file with Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT

When I print the path , it doesn't show the exact path.

CODE :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("text/plain");
startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                String filePath = uri.getPath();

                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                    filePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
}
```

output: `/document/primary:Documents/Test.txt`

expected output: `sdcard/Documents/Test.txt`

Comment: Your code snippet is seems right but why are you using `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` if you have implemented a activity then use `classname.this` for context.

Comment: The output is correct. Although you are messing around with it and did not tell the whole truth as it will have been `content:///<provider>/document/primary:Documents/Test.txt` ... Well... if you had used `uri.toString();` instead. Its in `content sheme` format. Not in a `file system` path. You can use it to open the file. No need for a file scheme. Please tell the problems you have with that sheme.